# Laravel 5.2 Edit button not displaying modal content when click

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am a new programmer in Laravel 5.2.4. I ran into a problem while i was trying to edit a button on social network app am trying to create. The edit button did not pop up. Probably I might be doing something wrong. Kindly assist. this is my code.

****My app.js file****

```
var postId = 0;
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('edit').on(2).on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var postBody = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
      postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
      $('#post-body').val(postBody);
      $('#edit-modal').modal();

    });

$('modal-save').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url:url,
    data: {body: $('#post-body').val(), postId: postId, _token: token}
})
    .done(function (msg){
        console.log(msg['message']);

});

});
```

****My dashboard.php controller****

```
 @extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
@include('includes.message-block')
<section class="row new-post">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <header><h3>What do you have to say?</h3></header>
        <form action="{{url('createpost')}}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" rows="5" placeholder="Your Post"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Post</button>
            <input  type="hidden" name="_token"  value="{{Session::token()}}" name="_token">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="row posts">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <header><h3>What other people say...</h3></header>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
<article class="post" data-postid="{{$post->id}}">
    <p>{{$post->body}}</p>  
    <div class="info">
        Posted by {{$post->user->first_name}} on {{$post->created_at }}
    </div>
<div class="interaction">
<a href="#">Like</a>   |
<a href="#">Dislike</a> | 
@if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
<a href="#">Edit</a>   | 
<a href="{{route('post.delete', ['post_id'=>$post->id])}}">Delete</a>   |                       
@endif                                                                                                                                      
</div>
</article>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="edit-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
    </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post-body">Edit the Post</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="post-body" id ="post-body" row ="5"></textarea>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    var token = '{{Session::token()}}';
var url = '{{route('edit')}}';
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Please be specific about your problem with few lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to solve this riddle after going through the programme next stage.
The Affected Area is app.js file and the dashboard.php

```
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('edit').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
There should be dot before the find edit
//corrected version
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('.edit').on(2).on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
```

Also on the dashboard.blade.php
 there should be a class edit before the edit

```
@if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
    <a href="#">Edit</a>   | 
    <a href="{{route('post.delete', ['post_id'=>$post->id])}}">Delete</a>   |                       
    @endif   

    <a href="#">Edit</a>   
    corrected version  
    <a href="#"class='edit'>Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js doesn't set click event on *Edit* link.

Instead

```
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('edit')
```

use something like

```
$('.post > .interaction > .edit-link')
```

And in dashboard.php on edit link put *.edit-link* class.